# Make custom commands for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want make new command line program for my ruby on rails application, but I can't found how I can make new command.
I mean, [this functional analogue](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/topics.console) in RoR.

Help me please, and tell me please how I can fix my problem.

Thanks a lot.

P.S. sorry about my English.

ADD1: I want create backend script for parse xmls and save its in database. I think, will be very good if I can use AR classes from my RoR application.

Comment: You want to know how to write something on the command-line, but don't show what experience you have writing code. We need a lot more information. Have you ever written a command-line application in Ruby? Have you got a good idea what you want to write this time? What have you tried as you try to solve this?

Comment: If RoR have interface for autoload classes and I can get access for all classes my RoR application (example: ActiveRecord, help classes...) it's will be very good.
Yes, i write console applications on Ruby, but I want integrate my code from conole application and web application on RoR.

Thanks your message

Comment: Rails has the [`runner`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) command, which is designed to offer you the same features as a Rails app, but without the GUI/HTTPd server. It'll load your Active Record models and use your database.yml file to let you connect to the database. This makes it trivial to write back-end code. Otherwise you need to use Active Record and load the database.yml file.

Comment: I used to find how work with runner but i don't found detail information, can you give link for me which have detail information about runner in rails?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+runner&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: You have not explained at all what you want this command line thing to do. Please explain it in detailed terms in your original post.

Comment: I add more information in ADD1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For command line prog just use rune as follows :

```
rails runner "model.method"
```

as in case of console and server you can also mention the environment for running.

For parsing xml there a lot of options like LibXML.

Comment: I hope this helps for me, thanks. I will test it's in the evening

Answer (score 1):

Create you rake task file in lib/tasks/my_self.rake
and write something like:

```
namespace :my_commands do
  task :this_command do
    puts "this is My Command"
  end
end
```

If you want access to your Applications Models you must initialize rails for you applications with your task including environment.rb:

```
# write task name with :environment if you use task with AR
namespace :my_commands do
  task this_command: :environment do
    puts "this is My Command"
    
    user = User.first
    puts user.name
  end
end
```

Now you can run you task code in terminal:
`$ rails my_commands:this_command`